# Finding the value of angles inside a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the following illustration $\angle RPQ = 50^\circ$ and $\angle PSR = 60^\circ$, then side $QS$ is congruent with side $SP$ if:

[image: Triangle]

$(1)$ $\angle RPS + \angle PQR = 50^\circ$

$(2)$ $\angle RPS + \angle QRP = 120^\circ$

According to the answer sheet, only $(1)$ is correct, but I say both are:
If I need sides $QS$ and $SP$ to be congruent then $\angle SPQ$ and $\angle PQR$ need both to be $30^\circ$, if $\angle SPQ$ is $30$ then $\angle RPS$ is $20$ so $\angle RPS + \angle PQR = 50^\circ$ so $(1)$ is correct.

If $\angle RPS + \angle QRP = 120$ then that means that $\angle SPQ = 30$, and $\angle QRP = 100$, then $\angle PQR = 30$ because $\angle RPQ = 50 + \angle PQR = 30 + \angle QRP = 100 = 180^\circ$ and $QS=SP$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "If RPS+QRP=120 then that means that SPQ=30" - why? And your argument for (1) is backwards (although all the implications are actually equivalences, so you can reverse them and get a correct argument).

Comment: Actually here second implication comes out to be correct due to given values and it needn't be correct generally. So here 2 is also correct.

Comment: If RPS+QRP=120 then I can say RPS=20 and since RPQ=50 then SPQ=30.

Comment: Oh, you so seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, both are correct
PS=SQ, means triangle SPQ is isoscale triangle
So, we can easily say angle SPQ=angle PQS
angle RPS + angle PQR =50 degree

Now for prove second
We know, Summation of all inner angle of a triangle is 180 degree
Now, angle PSR=60 degree
So, summation of other two angles must be 120 degree

Hence both are correct

Answer (score 0):

You are showing "from $PS=SQ$ follows (1) and (2)", whereas you must show backwards. The condition $\measuredangle PRS+\measuredangle RPS=120$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition.